# Convert hex string to float in little endian format

Tags: python, endianness

I am converting a hex string which I know is in **little endian format** as follows to float.

```
hex_string = '00e0b8bf'
to_int = int(hex_string, 16)
struct_packed = struct.pack(">i", to_int)
to_float = struct.unpack(">f", struct_packed)[0]
```

How can I convert **hex_string** to **little endian** format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bytes.fromhex` to get a byte representation of the hex value, then unpack using `<` for little-endian format:

```py
>>> x = '00e0b8bf'
>>> bytes.fromhex(x)
b'\x00\xe0\xb8\xbf'
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('<f',bytes.fromhex(x))[0]
-1.4443359375
```